# Angular Build error on Azure devops using Docker

Tags: angular, docker, azure-devops

Running Angular build on Azure devOps using docker. But getting error as in screenshot after successful build.

When executing build on local, working fine but giving error on Azure DevOps. Any workarounds how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the error is due to Angular's AOT compilation, have you ever tried to build the application in your local? That's means that you has an error that Angular's JIT compilation ignores. Sorry for not giving you more information.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to build is locally throught docker. But its giving node-sass error binary not found and exiting.